# Change from phpmyadmin to real database

Tags: phpmyadmin

I made a database using phpmyadmin and now i want to "move" this database to a server. Is it possible ? and if yes please tell me how.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, this is how you can do it:

> 1. in phpmyadmin select your database
> 2. Click Export
> 3. Select your export criteria(if you need to)
> 4. click go

This will generate an sql executable file, take it and run it where you want you store your database